# Longest Common Sequence optimization problem

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming, longest-substring

I am trying to solve a problem which finds Longest Common Sequence between two strings. I used dynamic programming (DP) and I tried to optimize it. But I still get a timeout on HackerRank and I do not know why. I use the iterative version of Hunt–Szymanski algorithm.

Instead of using one matrix, I used only two rows and I interchange them. I also eliminated all common characters at the beginning and the end of the strings. I also used the iterative version of the algorithm. How else could I optimize this?

This is my code:

```
def commonChild(s1, s2):
    nr = 0
    while s1[0]==s2[0]:
        nr+=1
        s1=s1[1::]
        s2=s2[1::]
    while s1[-1]==s2[-1]:
        nr+=1
        s1=s1[0:-1]
        s2=s2[0:-1]

    row1 = [0]*(len(s1)+1)
    row2 = [0]*(len(s1)+1)


    for i in range(1,len(s1)+1):
        for j in range(1,len(s2)+1):


            if s1[j-1]==s2[i-1]:
                row2[j]=row1[j-1]+1


            else:

                row2[j]=max(row2[j-1], row1[j])


        row1=row2
        row2=[0]*(len(s1)+1)


    return row1[-1]+nr
```

Thank you.

Comment: Could you expand your question to be a [mcve]? Also, what is "DP"?

Comment: @Alex  DP is dynamic programming. Sure, firstly i eliminate all first and last elements that are the same, retaining the number of these elements in nr. After that, i use the iterative version of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunt%E2%80%93Szymanski_algorithm this algorithm, and instead of using a matrix, i only use two rows which i interchange (row1 and row2). I retain the number of same elements end at the end i add nr which i calculated and the beginning

Comment: You should update your question with these details. Add comments to the code and provide example input and corresponding output. That is a [mcve].

Comment: Are you sure the problem is a time out? I have noticed several bugs in your implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good attempt.

Notice that you use index `i` to loop through `s1` in the outer loop and index `j` to loop through `s2` in the inner loop.

You should let `s1` and `s2` to have the length of `s2` plus `1`, the inner loop length plus `1`.

Also, you mistakenly use `j` to access `s1` and `i` to access `s2` in your implementation.

Lastly, to overcome the timeout issue, rather than the regular Python, use PyPy instead.

```
def commonChild(s1, s2):
    nr = 0
    while s1[0]==s2[0]:
        nr+=1
        s1=s1[1::]
        s2=s2[1::]
    while s1[-1]==s2[-1]:
        nr+=1
        s1=s1[0:-1]
        s2=s2[0:-1]
    #row1 = [0]*(len(s1)+1)
    #row2 = [0]*(len(s1)+1)
    row1 = [0]*(len(s2)+1)
    row2 = [0]*(len(s2)+1)
    for i in range(1,len(s1)+1):
        for j in range(1,len(s2)+1):
            #if s1[j-1]==s2[i-1]:
            if s1[i-1] == s2[j-1]:
                row2[j]=row1[j-1]+1
            else:
                row2[j]=max(row2[j-1], row1[j])
        row1=row2
        #row2=[0]*(len(s1)+1)
        row2 = [0]*(len(s2)+1)
    return row1[-1]+nr
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i was able to solve this by changing from Py3 to PyPy3 and it worked fine both with my first implementation and with the changes you brought. Thanks again!